# How do I remove a row from a Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

I have a very simple setup, a grid called #list with a datasource populated with records to display.

I have a button on each row with an onClick event that calls this function:

```
    // Soft-Delete person
    var processURL = crudServiceBaseUrl + '?method=deletePerson';
    function deletePerson(id){
        if (confirm('#getResource("person.detail.confirmdel")#')) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: processURL,
                data: {
                    PERS_KY: id
                },
                success: function (data){
                    var thingToDelete = "tr:eq("+id+")";
                    var grid = $("#list").data("kendoGrid");
                    grid.removeRow(thingToDelete);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert("Error while deleting person"+ "\n"+ xhr + "\n"+ textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    }

The server-side stuff works fine, the interaction with the database is good. However, the row does not disappear from the grid.

Anyone?

==============================================================================

In answer to the comments below, here is the revised function:

var processURL = crudServiceBaseUrl + '?method=deletePerson';
function deletePerson(id, row){
    if (confirm('#getResource("person.detail.confirmdel")#')) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: processURL,
            data: {
                PERS_KY: id
            },
            success: function (data){
                var thingToDelete = row;
                var grid = $("#list").data("kendoGrid");
                grid.removeRow(thingToDelete);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert("Error while soft-deleting person"+ "\n"+ xhr + "\n"+ textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This all works fine, the database is populated and grid.removeRow() makes the row fade out, but then the page reloads, which I don't want.

Any idea how to stop the page reloading?

Comment: Your code seems ok, it should work. have you try debug whether thingToDelete contain the right row/element ?

Comment: Have you tries changing type from 'POST to 'DELETE'? We would probably need more information to fix this, can you post your processURL function and the server side code implementing your delete api?

Comment: Also you could try using a fiddler to see what your code is sending and any error message from your api. Telerik have a free fiddler here http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Hi all.
@machun. Yes that was one of the problems. The 'id' I was passing in represented the database id of the record, not the row element. I have since altered the function to take a second argument of row and changed the line to "grid.removeRow(row);". This makes the row disappear (yay!) but leads to a further problem later on (boo!)

Comment: @Padhraic, "Http method DELETE is not supported by this URL" :-(

Comment: @MichaelCasey maybe you can update the code on your question, and add more explanation

Comment: The revised function looks like this:

Answer (score 15):

below code show how to delete rows using custom delete command.

```
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            {
                command: [{ name: "edit" }, {
                    name: "Delete", imageClass: "k-icon k-i-close", click: function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));
                        if (confirm('Do you really want to delete this record?')) {
                            var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
                            dataSource.remove(dataItem);
                            dataSource.sync();
                        }
                    }
                }], title: "&nbsp;", width: "200px"
            }
        ]
    });
```

Hope this may help

Answer (score 2):

The grid already supports create, update and deleting of records. You should not try to implement it on your own.

You need to define destroy on your datasource like [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline)

```
transport: {
    read:  {
             url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
    },
    destroy: {
               url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
    }
}
```

Also you can turn on a delete [confirmation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-editable.confirmation)

```
    editable: {
     confirmation: "Are you sure that you want to delete this record?"
   }
```

**EDIT:**
In order to conditionally show delete buttons you can hook up the DataBound-Event of the grid. You also need some indication wheter or not to show the button. I used a property called HideButton in my example. Maybe you have to adjust the class .k-grid-delete the rest should work.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
         ... other configuration ...
         dataBound: onDataBound
});

function onDataBound(e) {
        var grid = this;
        var ds = grid.dataSource;
        var max = ds.data().length;
        for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            var currentUid = ds.at([i]).uid;
            var currentRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
            if (ds.at(i).HideButton) {
                var editButton = $(currentRow).find(".k-grid-delete");
                editButton.hide();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact I can't use the 'destroy' attribute in the normal way because the 'Delete' button must not appear on every row. There is some conditional logic which I have to run first which allows the button to appear or not. I'm *really* not sure how I would add conditional logic with the destroy attribute, although I'm open to advice on that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Other way to remove row with kendo ui

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
        {       
            command: [
            {
             name: "remove",
              text: '',
              iconClass : 'k-icon k-i-delete',
              
              click: (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                const row = $(e.target).closest('tr')[0];
    
                const grid = $(e.target).closest('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
                grid.removeRow(row);
                //grid.saveChanges(); //if you need to immediately push changes on the server 
              }
             },
         
    ]
    });
```