# JQuery Remove() doesn't actually delete the row(s) from grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I been working on removing rows from a grid and finally after some searching am now able to remove rows from my grid. It was a yahoo moment that lasted only a brief few seconds because I went to double check that the row was truly deleted and noticed that it isn't actually deleted per say, just hidden.

I found this out by using the filter that I have in the grid and when I filtered for one of the removed rows data, it appeared again, and once I cleared the filter all deleted rows appeared again.

So now I am confused on a number of things, why are the rows only hidden and not really removed and how do I actually remove rows from the grid without having to use ajax to delete the row then rebind the table again, and the reason why this wouldnt be good is because any data that is in the grid will be lost and have to be reentered again. Because as I am looking at it now, if I am just hiding the row then when I go to take all the data from the grid and add it to a database that I'm going to have an issue because I have rows being removed for a reason.

I created a basic dojo [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@Cwm/AfUHo) to show that what I am saying is actually happening.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var junkData = [{
      "DiscountID": 1,
      "DealerDiscount": "15"
    }, {
      "DiscountID": 2,
      "DealerDiscount": "16"
    }, {
      "DiscountID": 3,
      "DealerDiscount": "17"
    }, {
      "DiscountID": 4,
      "DealerDiscount": "18"
    }, {
      "DiscountID": 5,
      "DealerDiscount": "19"
    }, {
      "DiscountID": 6,
      "DealerDiscount": "20"
    }, {
      "DiscountID": 7,
      "DealerDiscount": "21"
    }, {
      "DiscountID": 8,
      "DealerDiscount": "22"
    }, {
      "DiscountID": 9,
      "DealerDiscount": "23"
    }

  ];

  ShowGrid(junkData);
});

function ShowGrid(userdata) {

  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    noRecords: {
      template: "No Records Available"
    },
    dataSource: {
      data: userdata
    },
    schema: {
      model: {
        DiscountID: "DiscountID"
      }
    },
    filterable: {
      mode: "row"
    },
    columns: [{
        title: "<input id='checkAll', type='checkbox', class='check-box' />",
        template: "<input name='Selected' class='checkbox' type='checkbox'>",
        width: "30px"
      }, {
        field: "DealerDiscount",
        title: "Dealer Discount",
        template: "<div style='text-align: center'>#= DealerDiscount #</div>"
      }, {
        title: "Delete",
        template: "<button type='button' class='removeit'>X</button>"
      }
    ],
    scrollable: true,
    height: 856
  });
}

$(document).on('click', 'button.removeit', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: and where is your code?

Comment: I supplied a dojo

Comment: Wow, tough crowd. I assume that me providing a link to the code and making it easier on people that may not have the time to start a new project in Visual Studio and may not have Kendo UI deserves a down vote and a vote to close. Maybe the link in my last sentence was overlooked and someone thought I was being lazy?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I was not aware how to do all this in here

Comment: Links to demos are great, it's just that the code does need to be in the question for it to be complete. No problem :)

Comment: @4castle, my apologies, I didn't think of it that way. I was trying to make things easier is all and have no idea on how to do what you did in the edit. I'll have to look into what you did :)

Comment: There is a code snippet button that looks like `<>`, to the right of the image button. It opens an interface for code snippets. You can edit the snippet I inserted by clicking on "edit the above snippet" in the preview.

Comment: Are you trying to delete lines from `junkData`?

Comment: I think there is an answer you are looking for :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183593/how-do-i-remove-a-row-from-a-kendo-grid

Comment: @ms_nitrogen, I would say yes, however in a live environment when the grid is populated by an ajax call to the database, then if I say yes then I would actually need to delete the data from the table and that would be detrimental. So I wouldn't want to do that

Comment: @DamianBartosik,  I looked over that link and I thought about that approach, but the grid would be populated by a table and dont really want to delete any of the rows in that table

Comment: hmmmm...maybe I can just create an object and delete the rows from the object and rebind to the object instead of making calls to the database???

Comment: @ms_nitrogen, yes you are correct, my mistake in saying no

Comment: @Chris In this approach you would remove only row from an instance of that grid, so your table would remain the same. If you only remove it from Html DOM, when you filter things, grid plugin renders it again without knowing you deleted the element.
P.S. You don't need to make call to the database :)

Comment: Well I think I got everything figured out, the only real question now is how do I get the ID on that button click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have removed only row from UI but the still that record/data available in grid'd model/datasource so you must remove the data/record from the model also.

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.removeit', function () {
   var currentrow = $(this).closest('tr');
   currentrow.remove();
   var grid1 = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
   var currItem = grid1.dataSource.getByUid($(currentrow).data('uid'));
   grid1.dataSource.remove(currItem); 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I am a little confused though with the currentrow, I looked at the console log and not sure how you get the uid from it

Comment: uid is the automated generated field by kendo.js. this thing help us to identify the every row uniquely. you can also check the same thing by using inspect element of tr element.

Answer (score 1):

The removed row will be present in the `kendo ui` till you push changes to server.
To remove the row entirely you need to use
`grid.saveChanges()`

So the code below will remove row from server as well from ui

```
  const row = $(e.target).closest('tr')[0];
const grid = $(e.target).closest('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
grid.removeRow(row);
grid.saveChanges() //comment if you need to remove only from ui
```