# Remove row from Kendo UI Grid with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a Kendo UI grid and for deleting a row I am using a custom button with bootstrap that when I click on it, with ajax I call a web api method to remove that row and if it is successfully deleted that row removes it from the DOM. (I'm not using the command destroy of kendo)

The problem I have is that if I try to filter that row that was removed, it appears again in the grid and it seems that it was not removed at all.

This is my Kendo UI grid:

```
var table = $("#grid").kendoGrid({                
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/api/customers",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10
    },               
    height: 550,
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    columns: [{
        template: "<a href='' class='btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-remove js-delete' title='Delete' data-customer-id= #: Id #></a>",
        field: "Id",
        title: "&nbsp;",
        filterable: false,
        sortable: false,
        width: 50,
        attributes: {
            style: "text-align: center" 
        }
    }, {
        field: "Name",
        title: "Name",
        width: 100,
    }, {
        field: "LastName",
        title: "LastName",
        width: 100,
    }, {
        field: "Email",
        title: "Email",
        width: 150
    }]
});
```

And this is my jQuery code for deleting a row:

```
$("#grid").on("click", ".js-delete", function () {
     var button = $(this);
     if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this customer?")) {
         $.ajax({
             url: "/api/customers/" + button.attr("data-customer-id"),
             method: "DELETE",
             success: function () {
                 button.parents("tr").remove();  //This part is removing the row but when i filtered it still there.
             }
         });
     }
 });
```

I know that in jQuery DataTables when can do something like this:

```
 table.row(button.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
```

How can i do something like this with Kendo UI using jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a row from a Kendo Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183593/how-do-i-remove-a-row-from-a-kendo-grid)

Comment: You need to use `dataSource.remove(dataItem);` -
 example in the duplicate link above.  Many more examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+row+from+kendo+grid

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't ever play with a Kendo's widget DOM. Always use it's methods instead.

Using Grid's [`removeRow()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-removeRow):

```
$("#grid").on("click", "button.remove", function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr"),
        grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    grid.removeRow($tr);
});
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EkuTab/2)

---

Using DataSource's [`remove()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-remove):

```
$("#grid").on("click", "button.remove", function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr"),
        grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"),
        dataItem = grid.dataItem($tr);

    grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
});
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EkuTab)

Comment: Thank you man! I read the documentation of Kendo grid but with this kind of examples it is more clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

My usage was a little different.  I have a custom delete button, so I needed to delete by `ID`, not `UID`.
You should be able to match on any field value instead of ID.

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var dataItem = grid.dataSource.get(ID);
var row = grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']");
grid.removeRow(row);
```

We were trying to prevent messing with the controller, and this calls the existing delete function.

Answer (score 1):

The removed row will be present in the `kendo ui` till you push changes to server.
To remove the row entirely you need to use
`grid.saveChanges()`

So the code below will remove row from server as well from ui

```
const row = $(e.target).closest('tr')[0];
const grid = $(e.target).closest('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
grid.removeRow(row);
grid.saveChanges() //comment out if you need to remove only from ui
```